# How to read data from a file from within a function

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to make my code more efficient, specifically the reading of data from a text file. Here is a snapshot of what it looks like now:

```
values V(name); 
    V.population = read_value(find_line_number(name, find_in_map(pop, mapping)));
    V.net_growth = read_value(find_line_number(name, find_in_map(ngr, mapping)));
... // and so on
```

Basically, the `read_value` function creates an `ifstream` object, opens the file, reads one line of data, and closes the file connection. This happens many times. What I want to do is to open the file once, read every line that is needed into the struct, and then close the file connection.

Here is the creating `values` struct function with parameters:

```
static values create_struct(std::string name, std::map<std::string, int> mapping) {
    values V(name); 
    V.population = read_value(find_line_number(name, find_in_map(pop, mapping)), file);
    V.net_growth = read_value(find_line_number(name, find_in_map(ngr, mapping)), file);
    // more values here
    return V;
}
```

The function that calls `create_struct` is shown below:

```
void initialize_data(string name) {
    // read the appropriate data from file into a struct
    value_container = Utility::create_struct(name, this->mapping);
}
```

I am thinking of instead defining the ifstream object in the function `initialize_data`. Given what is shown about my program, would that be the best location to create the file object, open the connection, read the values, then close the connection? Also, would I need to pass in the ifstream object into the `create_values` struct, and if so, by value, reference or pointer?

Comment: How about opening the file in the calling function, and then pass it as an argument to `read_value`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would I pass the istream object by reference or pointer?

Comment: If you are concerned with the efficiency so much then why do you pass your strings and mapping by copy/value, instead of, say, const reference? Also, not sure how your read_value/find_line_number works, but it might be more efficient (if the files are just few MBs in size) to read the whole file at once into some string, and then operate on it.

Comment: If you have an object, pass by reference. If you have a pointer to an object, do what you think feel best. :)

Comment: @DanM. The file is formatted in a way that when an object is created, it reads only a small portion of the file, depending on the object name. Say, if the name was "Charlie", the function would read lines 25 - 45. Also, the file is small, so I could read it into a string, but the manipulation part would be trickier... Also, I will fix the const reference instead of passing by value, thank you for that tip.

Comment: @YuriyF: Does you file contain offsets to the start of the lines so that you can seek to them? If not, the cleanest is to have the function(s) read through the file once, picking whatever is needed along the way -- but you need to know all the things you will need to keep before you start. If you can't know/keep them, you will have to seek back to the beginning every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to create your ifstream object first and pass it as reference to your parser.  Remember to seek the stream back to the beginning before you leave your function, or when you start to read.

The RAII thing to do would be to create a wrapper object that automatically does this when it goes out of scope.

```
class ifStreamRef{
    ifStreamRef(std::ifstream& _in) : mStream(_in){}
    ~ifStreamRef(){mStream.seekg(0);}
    std::ifstream& mStream;
}
```

Then you create a wrapper instance when entering a method that will read the fstream.

```
void read_value(std::ifstream& input, ...){
    ifStreamRef autoRewind(input);
}
```

Or, since the Ctor can do the conversion...

```
void read_value(ifStreamRef streamRef, ...) {
    streamRef.mStream.getLine(...);
}
```

std::ifstream itself follows RAII, so it will close() the stream for you when your stream goes out of scope.

---

The long answer is that you should read up on dependency injection.  Don't create dependencies inside of objects/functions that can be shared.  There are lots of videos and documents on dependency injection and dependency inversion.

Basically, construct the objects that your objects depend on and pass them in as parameters.

The injection now relies on the interface of the objects that you pass in.  So if you change your ifStreamRef class to act as an interface:

```
class ifStreamRef{
    ifStreamRef(std::ifstream& _in) : mStream(_in){}
    ~ifStreamRef(){mStream.seekg(0);}

    std::string getLine(){
        // todo : mStream.getLine() + return "" on error;
    } 
    bool eof() { return mStream.eof(); }
    std::ifstream& mStream;
}
```

Then later on you can change the internal implementation that would take a reference to `vector<string>&` instead of `ifstream`...

```
class ifStreamRef{
    ifStreamRef(std::vector<string>& _in) : mStream(_in), mCursor(0){}
    ~ifStreamRef(){}

    std::string getLine(){
        // todo : mStream[mCursor++] + return "" on error;
    } 
    bool eof() { return mCursor >= mStream.size(); }
    std::vector<string>& mStream;
    size_t mCursor;
}
```

---

I have oversimplified a few things.